# How to show report output below a submitted form?

Tags: forms

I'm creating a form with a submit button. Below the submit button after the user submits some input data, I want to display the results of a report that I create by querying the database using the input variables that the user input on the form.

I can get the submitted form variables to appear by going to nameofmodule_form_submit() and typing `$form_state['rebuild'] = TRUE;`, but how do I add to the HTML of the page?
If I can't add to the same page (below the Submit button), how do I add it to the next page? And in which function should I do my db_select processing?

Comment: it would probably be simplest to override the redirect in the submit function to a page that includes a view using contextual filters - you can easily build the url with the given field values in the submit function, and the view will read those, producing your report.

Comment: How do I go to another page on submit? Can you provide some example code?

Comment: see here (https://www.drupal.org/node/290462) for some further info